# Wordpress - Images not showing up in Media Library

Tags: wordpress, image

for some reason, WordPress images not showing up in Media Library since yesterday moreover when I try to upload an image is getting the error "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.
I tried everything I read, fix permission, update everything, disabled all plugins, enable default theme, install some plugins like Hotfix, and Media sync, etc upgraded `PHP` with no luck,
when I'm going to the Media library the image is like [grid view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCfbk.png)

when I'm going to list view it shows blank thumbnails without the option to delete them.
[list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRHbs.png)

After my deeper investigation i figure out the following the "no title" created every time im trying to upload a photo.
there are 2 issues

1. i have set the media settings to  Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders
   But when im uploading a photo for some reasons the upload goes in older folders and not Feb 2023.
2. if i disable this feature then the photos upload goes to the roor of the upload folder and again in the library shows error.
3. if i manually upload the photo via FTP in a specific folder also the last uploaded file shows as "no title"

Another update is that when in the library is selected “All media items” and “all dates” not showing anything if i choose a specific month it shows the media.
Moreover if i delete the folders from the upload it still available in the gui bit without photos.
But im still facing issues to upload or to see all the media.

could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the allowed memory limit for PHP needs to be increased. If you have access to update this values, consider updating it. It's found in your php.ini files. The default is usually 64MB. You could try adding multiples of 64 MB. So 256MB should be fine. Good luck!

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your quick response. Unfortunately this is not the problem my defaults on php are :
memory_limit
384M
max_execution_time
180
max_input_time
180
post_max_size
128M
upload_max_filesize
128M
opcache.enable
on (Default)
disable_functions
opcache_get_status

Comment: Consider increasing the max_execution_time to 1900.

Comment: Finally something change but not for good :) now it shows No media items found.

Comment: I think that the issue is hiding behind the "no title" media files but i cant find how to delete them